# Adjust max multiplier for Intel 8550U processor

Tags: windows, cpu

CPU-Z shows, that allowed multipliers for Intel 8550U processor are 4-40.

When setting "Maximum processor state" to 99% under Windows power options, then multiplier is usually 19, which corresponds to 1.8 GHz. When "Maximum processor state" is "100%", then multiplier is usually 40 (maximal value), but in this case fan starts working loudly.

Is there a way to change max allowed multiplier to e.g. 30 (out of 40)? Computer is Lenovo Thinkpad T480 laptop.

Comment: User is asking about underclocking, not overclocking. You are allowed to decrease the multiplier on a locked processor. Laptop BIOSes generally don't have the option to do this so you need a software tool like ThrottleStop to do it. Thank you for deleting my answer by the way @Ramhound.

Answer (score 1):

Using Throttlestop following settings worked for me:

```
Throttlestop -> TPL -> "Turbo Boost Long Power Max"   -> change to 12 (default was 25)
Throttlestop -> TPL -> "Turbo Boost Short Power Max"  -> change to 12 (default was 29)
```

Now "Throttle" radio button is frequently checked in "Throttlestop" main interface.

Result is, that average CPU multiplier is smaller and fan works quietly.